# Flask and GoogleMaps Api Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to manage Google Maps Api in order to work within Flask.
However it doesn't give any error, but it doesn't render the map itself.
It work perfectly on simple .html however Flask is having problem rendering map.js file itself

map.js

```
    // Initiation of marker for Google Maps Api
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {
            lat: 52.857500,
            lng: -8.987437
        }
    });

    var labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var locations = [{
        lat: 52.857500,
        lng: -8.987437
    }];

    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });
    });

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });
}
```

Flask Code

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<!-- content -->
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <div class="row center"></div>

      <h2 class="header center black-text">How to approach our office ? </h2>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">85 Aughanteeroe<br> Gort Road <br> Ennis <br> Co. Clare<br>V95 CXV2<br>Ireland</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row center" id="map">

        <br>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCef1gneSCdkePrWnkXROPQUynW490rnd4&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/map.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Whats your current render output? and expected render output?

Comment: Sorry Problem solved itself somehow. It is working fine :) Thanks in advance